# Reuters dataset classes

Tags: svm, weka, libsvm, text-classification, reuters

I am researching on text classification using SVM. I am using reuters 21578 modapte dataset in arff format and classifying it using weka. I am getting two classes after classification viz., (-inf-0.5] and (0.5-inf). What are these classes? And how should I proceed to study on learning svm?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: I am using weka. Its an application. The results are -

=== Confusion Matrix ===

    a    b   <-- classified as
 6044   76 |    a = '(-inf-0.5]'
 1049  601 |    b = '(0.5-inf)'

I am not getting if I am doing the classifcation right or not. I am using 250 attributes and 7770 instances of the file Reuters-Acq-Train-ModApte. And applying LibSVM on the 'acq' attribute.

Comment: yes, it your result. Could you share your code, to present how did you the classification?